# How to erase the intersecting part of the two rectangles in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am developing a speech bubble for my project. I am using a frameless `QDialog` wherein I painted two elliptical rectangles in an intersecting way as shown below.

[image: a picture of the problem]

How could I remove the intersecting part here? I have marked that part in the image.

I am very new to Qt. The code is:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.save();
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QPen pen(QColor(65, 167, 243), 3,Qt::SolidLine);
QBrush brush(QColor(255, 255, 255,204));

painter.setPen(pen);
painter.setBrush(brush);

QPainterPath rounded_rect;
rounded_rect.addRoundedRect(QRectF(20, 0, 180, 100), 16, 16);
rounded_rect.addRoundedRect(QRectF(0, 50 - 20, 40, 40 ), 16, 16);


painter.setClipPath(rounded_rect);
QRegion maskregion = painter.clipRegion();
setMask(maskregion);

painter.drawPath(rounded_rect);
painter.restore();
```

Comment: You should **really** use stackoverflow's image hosting. Remember that stackoverflow content is meant to be at least complete, even if not quite relevant, for many years to come. Third-party content comes and goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks bkausbk.Here is the code:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.save();
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QPen pen(QColor(65, 167, 243), 3,Qt::SolidLine);
QBrush brush(QColor(255, 255, 255,204));

painter.setPen(pen);
painter.setBrush(brush);

QPainterPath rounded_rect1,rounded_rect2,round;
rounded_rect1.addRoundedRect(QRectF(20, 0, 180, 100), 16, 16);
rounded_rect2.addRoundedRect(QRectF(0, 50 - 20, 40, 40 ), 16, 16);

round = rounded_rect1 + rounded_rect2;
painter.setClipPath(round);

QRegion maskregion = painter.clipRegion();

setMask(maskregion);

painter.drawPath(round);
painter.restore();
```

Comment: Your use of `painter.save()` and `painter.restore()` is redundant. You are using a new painter, after all.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You should take a look at Qt documentation:

- [QWidget::setMask()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask)
- [QRegion](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregion.html)
- [Shape Clock Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html) for a demonstration

**Edit:** You should change your code to following (not tested!)

```
QPainterPath p1, p2;
p1.addRoundedRect(QRectF(20, 0, 180, 100), 16, 16);
p2.addRoundedRect(QRectF(0, 50 - 20, 40, 40 ), 16, 16);
p1 += p2; // or -= if you want to remove that part

QRegion r(p1.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
setMask(r);
```

**Edit 2:** Another solution is to overwrite paintEvent()

Instead of creating a mask, one could paint on transparent window by overwriting `paintEvent` and painting the background of a arbitrary complex form. However I'm not sure if this is working for QDialog based windows.

Comment: I have updated my code also.How can I change it to erase the intersecting part ?

Comment: QRegion r = p1.toFillPolygon();
This creates an error saying cannot convert QPolyganF to QRegion. 
p1 -= p2 results in the following image [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/bi2r76.png[/IMG] Which is not expected one.

Comment: Insteadt of -= operator one could use += operator. It depends on if you want to intersect or subtract that rect from the other.